# Unit test mat-menu with Karma-Jasmine

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine, angular-cdk

I have a mat-menu in which content may differ regarding user. I try to write unit test but from what I see, jasmine doesn't see the CDK `div`, so I cannot grab menu entries.

My template:

```html
<button id="account" mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Profile">
    <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item *ngxPermissionsOnly="PERMISSION.USER_LIST" id="user-list" (click)="usersList()">
        <mat-icon>recent_actors</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item *ngxPermissionsOnly="PERMISSION.INFORMATIONS" id="informations" (click)="infoList()">
        <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item id="logout" (click)="logout()">
        <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-menu>
```

The unit test:

```js
let component: HeaderComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture < HeaderComponent > ;

const providers: any[] = headerProviders;

beforeEach(async (() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                HeaderComponent,
                NgxPermissionsRestrictStubDirective
            ],
            providers: providers,
            imports: [
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                BrowserModule,
                CommonModule,
                CommonSogetrelModule,
                FlexLayoutModule,
                SharedMaterialModule,
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
}));

it('should not display elements which needs permissions', () => {
    fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#account').click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(logoutBtn).toBeTruthy('Le bouton Déconnexion doit être affiché');
    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#user-list')).toBeFalsy();

});
```

I've tried with

```
console.info(fixture.nativeElement.parentNode);
const menu = fixture.nativeElement.parentNode.querySelector('.mat-menu-panel');
expect(menu).toBeTruthy();
```

What I can see with the `console.info` is that there's no CDK `div` on the page, and so obviously the `.mat-menu-panel` isn't found.

Any idea about how to test the mat-menu content?

Comment: Make sure you have `MatMenuModule` and `MatIconModule` in your `imports` array. You most likely have it since you are not getting errors for compiling.

Comment: Yes I do have them in SharedMaterialModule

Comment: have you tried `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#account')).nativeElement.click()` and `expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#logout'))).toBeTruthy()`, `expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#user-list'))).toBeFalsy()` ?, still I think you should add whatever the console output is, or the output of the test, actually both.

Answer (score 5):

MatMenuHarness is the proper way to test the mat-menu but it has a tiny unintuitive detail about it. Given:

```html
<div class="view-contract__portal-header">
  <h2>Counterparties</h2>
  <button
    mat-stroked-button
    color="primary"
    data-testid="add-counterparty"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
  >
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> Add counterparty
  </button>
</div>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" data-testid="add-counterparty-menu">
  <button
    *ngFor="let role of roles"
    mat-menu-item
    [attr.data-testid]="'add-counterparty-' + role"
    (click)="addCounterparty(role)"
  >
    {{ role }}
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Then MatMenuHarness should be instantiated by looking for the element to which the matMenuTriggerFor attribute is applied and NOT the actual mat-menu element.

```html
addCounterpartyMenu = await loader.getHarness<MatMenuHarness>(
  MatMenuHarness.with({
    selector: `[data-testid="add-counterparty"]`,
  }),
);
```

Comment: I keep getting:

Error: Failed to find element matching one of the following queries:
(MatMenuHarness with host element matching selector: ".mat-menu-trigger" satisfying the constraints: host matches selector "#emailMenu")

even tried calling it without "with" filters. Still no Harnesses returned.

Comment: @Tohid been long time since I coded in Angular, but maybe your element is hidden

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try it with the `MatMenuHarness`.

https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuHarness

```js
it('should not display elements which needs permissions', async () => {
    let loader: HarnessLoader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let menu = await testHarness.loader.getHarness(MatMenuHarness);
    let items = await menu.getItems();
    expect(items.length).toBe(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are doing all in the same clock interaction, because of that, the DOM will not be updated until the next clock.

To handle this you can use [fakeAysnc](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync) and [tick](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-tick-function) of Angular.

I think we can rewrite your test with fakeAsync like this:

```
    it('should not display elements which needs permissions', fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#account').click();
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(logoutBtn).toBeTruthy('Le bouton Déconnexion doit être affiché');
        expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#user-list')).toBeFalsy();
      }));
```

I think it should work with that.